# Identifying outliers (not considering spatial relationship) in time-series data

Tags: shapefile, polygon, remote-sensing, time-series, spatial-outliers

The data I am working on is plant canopy cover (percentage within polygons (0-100%)) estimation from drones. This was collected over the course of 17 weeks. I was thinking on detecting outliers (not considering spatial relationship) for each flight (17 in total). Already tried z-score and modified z-score, but they don't seem to detect many outliers. The data was obtained from 417 polygons. Currently have the data in .shp and .xlsx format.

Which method should I use for the type of data described?

Sample data below **(showing only first 8 values and total average of 417 polygons)** :

```
CC210408    CC210412    CC210420    CC210429    CC210506    CC210514    CC210520    CC210524    CC210602    CC210609    CC210614    CC210623    CC210629    CC210708    CC210712    CC210720    CC210728    CC210810    CC210817
0.085738536 0.519386883 1.286098967 4.650546822 5.882511816 14.94510867 22.3624552  25.63828276 38.35260474 54.22633346 55.16728822 63.05233373 66.86726393 78.4164973  77.12807018 70.71556163 77.00342945 62.18413978 8.14067121
0.088754465 0.555881934 1.535312641 5.453433992 7.538149899 18.32185164 27.73727864 33.81852335 50.77764735 67.2300374  64.08313315 73.12311655 77.50315579 79.29669694 80.03655458 74.43414349 77.08982906 49.63860998 2.044910373
0.119932838 0.366086658 1.172739541 4.904969948 6.425838397 17.20832037 27.06464075 33.6363475  48.96899458 62.48479299 59.16542144 68.48285354 71.92865653 77.93512159 80.73903509 74.55668803 76.81183511 49.02754041 1.752410535
0.260681968 0.855734767 2.877500562 9.351675316 11.43198198 23.09930222 31.89978993 39.31431209 55.37493399 68.47902466 67.96683875 76.23563319 79.7420141  86.01151864 86.87015674 79.33684123 80.53917623 51.24990536 1.292272084
0.197458051 0.659045057 1.740440846 7.1441396   8.660814765 19.61109383 28.41406751 36.34305701 53.062113   72.97405312 65.73090832 75.43641929 79.51184912 85.36326659 84.3127193  80.28286225 81.30318311 51.28311258 1.261459479
0.203359744 0.751792115 1.781523938 7.192445474 8.410533423 19.23596604 28.91431674 35.04607354 51.41385801 68.47770712 70.33714228 78.22990399 80.42270066 86.02028472 85.0266489  81.77282757 81.98094555 52.5542085  0.694783764
0.002568295 0.084561703 0.201529465 1.864831954 1.116362818 3.260623343 6.638093712 10.19920814 21.82684002 41.57429204 37.81868373 36.26305277 39.74568996 52.36465164 45.01810155 46.02605863 46.82312934 33.52956989 0.645829289
0.1369277   0.54178416  1.51359228  5.794577587 7.066599014 16.52603802 24.71866321 30.5708292  45.68242738 62.20660583 60.03848798 67.26047329 70.81733287 77.91543392 77.01875519 72.44642612 74.50736112 49.9238695  2.261762391
```

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I have QGIS, ArcMap, and ArcGIS PRO. I used Excel to calculate z-score and modified z-score.

Comment: Always share data not as screenshot, but as actual data: otherwise, people willing to help first have to type all the cells on your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of an outlier is a completely different concept in time-series data. Any value that deviates far enough from the nonlinear trend of the time-series can start to behave as an outlier. The question is how far is too far and is it actually an anomaly. The anomaly question is for another time as it starts getting into large number theory and is a specific type of analysis.

You ask why does this matter? Outliers in time-sereies data can effect the stationarity, periodicity, serial autocorrelation and trend of the data which, is quite undesirable. This is why there are standard practices applied to time-series data in the exploratory data analysis (EDA) phase. One important part of this is smoothing the time-series. This effectively addresses both missing data and potential outliers that would effect trend. Here we will work through this in R (only a statistical software will have the tools for address this problem).

Here is the `dput` object for the first 8 rows of data which is part of the object that you would get with `read.csv("canopy.csv")`.

```
canopy <- structure(list(ï..20210408 = c(0.041948822, 0.397240856, 0.119932838, 
0.552183479, 0.810526497), X20210412 = c(0.362969132, 1.352987253, 
0.366086658, 1.820340502, 2.463736489), X20210420 = c(0.767363452, 
2.989516583, 1.172739541, 3.006747638, 4.433648223), X20210429 = c(4.459494324, 
10.48806619, 4.904969948, 10.18099741, 12.65135879), X20210506 = c(4.187720069, 
12.72657658, 6.425838397, 13.96396396, 16.55548053), X20210514 = c(10.40312903, 
24.41358971, 17.20832037, 31.74943702, 30.05555802), X20210520 = c(16.55689964, 
32.84543011, 27.06464075, 44.7420423, 41.00129958), X20210524 = c(20.19334908, 
40.85187224, 33.6363475, 54.61623138, 47.79841273), X20210602 = c(32.74604243, 
55.26944118, 48.96899458, 70.12032086, 64.05766254), X20210609 = c(47.03969342, 
78.97591526, 62.48479299, 83.01595109, 75.81302957), X20210614 = c(50.81376882, 
75.10915871, 59.16542144, 83.62894455, 76.70845896), X20210623 = c(59.83294204, 
83.63278786, 68.48285354, 86.56904169, 82.6352607), X20210629 = c(65.7701883, 
87.0502998, 71.92865653, 88.62306398, 85.74356998), X20210708 = c(76.64780293, 
89.39259792, 77.93512159, 89.86395333, 88.81535146), X20210712 = c(72.3504386, 
88.68385988, 80.73903509, 88.86666667, 88.65745614), X20210720 = c(71.35189661, 
85.62432139, 74.55668803, 83.42729475, 86.69916991), X20210728 = c(73.89636408, 
86.63500885, 76.81183511, 85.97555641, 86.26775966), X20210810 = c(51.98342294, 
68.89262497, 49.02754041, 58.85672577, 63.67896817), X20210817 = c(1.752841951, 
1.567442459, 1.752410535, 3.068228391, 1.031514916)), row.names = c(8L, 
9L, 3L, 13L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now lets add the require packages and create a date object. The dates "d" are parsed from the header names in the data.frame and then coerced into a data object. The gobbly goop syntax used in `gsub` is a regular expression for finding numbers in a string.

```
library(spatialEco)

d <- gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", names(canopy))
  ( d <- as.Date(d, "%Y%m%d") )
```

Now that we have our time-series data with associated dates we can move forward. First lets plot all of the time-series observations.

```
plot(d, canopy[1,], type="n", ylim=c(min(canopy),max(canopy)),
     ylab="Canopy percent", xlab="date", main="canopy time-series") 
  for(i in 1:nrow(canopy)){
    lines(d, canopy[i,])
  }
```

[image: raw time series]

Nothing looks too bad but there are a few suspicious local discontinuities ("spikes") in the bottom, and a few other, time-series. Now, we will use a local polynomial regression (LOESS) to smooth the data and, hopefully remove the outliers. The "p" parameter is how much to smooth the data (higher more smoothing). For filling missing data, I often start with p ~ 0.3 in order to adhere to the time-series as close as possible but, for smoothing I go higher to ensure that the results are outlier free. Here we use `apply` to iterate through the rows if the data.frame with the `impute.loess` function from the spatialEco package. This results in new data "smooth.canopy" that represents the smoothed time-series. We will plot these results as well.

```
p = 0.5
smooth.canopy <- t(apply(canopy, MARGIN=1, impute.loess, 
                   smooth=TRUE, s = p)) 

plot(d, smooth.canopy[1,], type="n", ylim=c(min(smooth.canopy),max(smooth.canopy)),
     ylab="Canopy percent", xlab="date", main="smoothed time-series") 
  for(i in 1:nrow(smooth.canopy)){
    lines(d, smooth.canopy[i,])
  }
```

[image: smoothed time-series]

As you can see, the resulting smoothed time-series is now better representing a trend process, not exhibiting the "spiky" effect that could represent measurement bias that effects the trend (outliers). However, lets add an actual outlier and examine this effect on a single time-series.

```
s <- as.numeric(canopy[1,])
  s[4] <- 20
plot(d,s, type="l")
  lines(d, impute.loess(s, smooth=TRUE, s = 0.5), col="red")
```

You can see that there is an outlier ~May and we can clearly minimize this effect by smoothing the data (red line). Please note that there is a trade off in how much you smooth your data. If you over smooth you can pull the time-series away from the trend. However, if you allow outliers or under smooth the resulting trend can be horribly biased. Many models (eg., AR(I), ARIMA) fit a linear trend to the time-series and in the presence of outliers can yield a very bad fit to the temporal process being modeled.

[image: single time-series]

Here we can write the data out.

```
smooth.canopy <- as.data.frame(smooth.canopy)
  names(smooth.canopy) <- paste0("CC", d)
write.csv(smooth.canopy, "smoothed_data.csv")
```